# How to bind Treeview without for/foreach loop in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am trying to bind Treeview without for/foreach loop, Is it possible? if yes then how?

Table structure -

```
Column1 | column2
------------------
root1   | val1
root1   | val2
root2   | val1
root2   | val2
```

I want tree structure without for/foreach loop -

```
root1 
   val1
   val2
root2
   val1
   val2
```

I have coding to do this treeview with for/foreach loop as shown below but I don't want to do like that.

```
foreach (Product product in category.ProductList)
{
   TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(product.ProductName, product.ProductID.ToString());
    parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Linq like the example bellow:

```
class Program
{
    class table
    {
        public string c1 { get; set; }
        public string c2 { get; set; }
    }
    class node
    {
        public string root { get; set; }
        public List<string> leafs { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<table> list = new List<table>()
        {
            new table(){ c1="root1", c2="val1"},
            new table(){ c1="root1", c2="val2"},
            new table(){ c1="root1", c2="val3"},
            new table(){ c1="root2", c2="val1"},
            new table(){ c1="root2", c2="val2"},
        };

        var tree = (from l in list
                   group l by l.c1 into t
                   select new node { 
                       root = t.Key, 
                       leafs = t.Select(e => e.c2).ToList() 
                   }).ToList();

        foreach(node n in tree)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.root);
            foreach(string l in n.leafs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", l);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have used foreach loop to display elements but i want to build tree without foreach/for loop like Treeview.BindData().. 
you have provided is not answer as I want already mentioned in question..

Can I bind your var tree directly as Treeview1.DataBind = tree ?